# Do I need to disable cron jobs?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, cron

I have installed the cron job as [proposed](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html). Now I'm wondering if there are reasons when I should disable it temporarily, so that nothing gets in conflict. Is that necessary at all or is Magento able to dismiss cron jobs when needed?

Do you disable them at any time? During updates or reindexing or whatever?

If so, how do you do that? Do you evaluate the existence of the var/maintenance.flag file in your crontab for the maintenance mode?

Comment: Magento cron jobs will not execute when maintenance mode is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable magento cronjobs anytime you want by using this command:

```
php bin/magento cron:remove
```

To re-enable cronjobs, run this command:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

The issue that you will face is,

- no auto indexing will perform after you disable crons,
- no catalog rules will apply
- no price index will run
- no custom cronjob will execute (Added by any module)

You can temporarily disable cronjob, if you are performing anything like indexing or update. But never think about disabling cronjob permanently, scheduling cronjobs is recommended by Magento.